# How to find a place in Famagusta?

Tags: history, northern-cyprus

I'm looking for a former British Base named Base 55 in Famagusta, North Cyprus.
What is it today:-
UN Base? 
Public place?

Comment: Do you mean Fort Bravo that is now in the green line UN buffer zone?

Comment: I really don't know

Comment: Where do you see the reference to Base 55? That might help.

Comment: The UK still controls two _Sovereign Base Areas_ on Cyprus, and one of them (Dhekelia) is near Famagusta. Hence, it might be that the place you are looking for is still British. (Incidentally, the BFPO numbers of the Dhekelia SBA are 58 and 59. Perhaps that has something to do with your 55.)

Answer (score 1):

On the island of Cyprus, the British Overseas Territory includes two base areas: Akrotiri, to the west not far from Limassol, and Dhekelia, in the east and proximate to Famagusta.

The British Sovereign Base Area (SBA) of Dhekelia lies at the edge of what is now the Buffer Zone, created by the 1974 division of Cyprus, and still an active military area. Fort Bravo is a redundant military facility within the Zone, also referred to as the Green Line.

According to British [military historian Malcolm Brooke](http://www.militaryhistories.co.uk/greenline/sba):

> Fort Bravo was a British Army camp whose purpose was to preserve the integrity of the Eastern SBA (at Dhekelia) against any force and prevent any internal security situation developing. The base also protected the Athna Forest Refugee Camp.

[image: Photo: Malcolm Brooke]

The Fort Bravo perimeter has fencing and prohibitive barbed wires, but there are disused watchtowers from which you can view the area. As seen from Brooke's photographs, you're able to approach the Fort and the map shows the Zone as it bisects the British military base.

[image]

The Buffer Zone is administered by the [United Nations Peacekeeping Force in Cyprus (UNFICYP](https://unficyp.unmissions.org/about-buffer-zone)).

> In the eastern part of the island, the Buffer Zone is interrupted by the British Sovereign Base Area of Dhekelia, where the UN does not operate. Another area the UN does not control is Varosha, the former resort town near Famagusta, now under the control of the Turkish military.